# swingで押されたボタンの履歴を表示したい

Tags: java, swing

以下のコードに `"Botton 5"`を追加するとして、`Botton5`を押した時、今までどのボタンを押したか履歴が表示されるようにするにはどう書き加えればよいでしょうか。

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class SwingTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
  JLabel label;

  public static void main(String[] args){
    SwingTest test = new SwingTest("SwingTest");

    test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    test.setVisible(true);
  }

  SwingTest(String title){
    setTitle(title);
    setBounds( 10, 10, 300, 200);

    label = new JLabel("");
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

    JButton btn1 = new JButton("Button 1");
    btn1.addActionListener(this);
    btn1.setActionCommand("Button 1");

    JButton btn2 = new JButton("Button 2");
    btn2.addActionListener(this);
    btn2.setActionCommand("Button 2");

    JButton btn3 = new JButton("Button 3");
    btn3.addActionListener(this);
    btn3.setActionCommand("Button 3");

    JButton btn4 = new JButton("Button 4");
    btn4.addActionListener(this);
    btn4.setActionCommand("Button 4");

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(btn1);
    p.add(btn2);
    p.add(btn3);
    p.add(btn4);

    getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String cmd = e.getActionCommand();

    if (cmd.equals("Button 1")){
      label.setText("open");
    }else if (cmd.equals("Button 2")){
      label.setText("print");
    }else if (cmd.equals("Button 3")){
      label.setText("rename");
    }else if (cmd.equals("Button 4")){
      label.setText("move");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

履歴を保持する`ArrayList`などのフィールドを用意して、

```java
private static List<String> history = new ArrayList<>();
```

ボタンがクリックされたら、そこにラベルを追加して、表示すればいいと思います。

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
    history.add(cmd);
    if (cmd.equals("Button 1")) {
        label.setText("open");
    } else if (cmd.equals("Button 2")) {
        label.setText("print");
    } else if (cmd.equals("Button 3")) {
        label.setText("rename");
    } else if (cmd.equals("Button 4")) {
        label.setText("move");
    } else if (cmd.equals("Button 5")) {
        label.setText(history.toString());
    }
}
```

表示の仕方などは工夫した方がいいと思いますが。